# PHP - reading data, storing in a variable, and then inserting into mysql database

Tags: php

I have select boxes which are generated from mysql.
When the user selects a select box value I want to read the data and then insert the data into the mysql database. I think I have everything sorted but I am having trouble trying to input the data into mysql. I am trying to read the data, then store it in a variable, and then send that variable value to the database. But with what I have, I am getting an error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in /Users/thomas/Sites/submit.php on line 12

I don't know PHP well enough to solve this problem so I am looking for some help?

```
 <?php
    $monday_am_task = $_POST['mondaycombo'];
    $i=1;
    $link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("timesheet",$link) or die(mysql_error());
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM am_task where am_task ='" .$monday_am_task."'";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $monday_am_task = mysql_fetch_field($result,$i);


    $SQL = "INSERT INTO `timesheet_submission`( `monday_am_task`) VALUES ('".$monday_am_task."')";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
 ?>
```

Thanks

EDIT: to represent the comments.

Comment: Why you make two database connection with same database?

Comment: purely for the fact that it would be a different task, didn't realise I could take that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `$monday_am_task` is an `Object` (see [mysql_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) documentation) and it can't be converted to a string on this line:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `timesheet_submission`( `monday_am_task`) VALUES ('".$monday_am_task."')";
```

That's why you have to replace it by `$monday_am_task->your_field` where `your_field` is a field from the table `am_tasks`.

EDIT: In response to your comment, the object attribute can be variable, demonstration:

```
<?php
   $obj = new stdClass();
   $obj->test = 2;
   $v = "test";
   print $obj->$v; // print 2
 ?>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! The idea on this though, is so that "your_field" would be dynamic, so where $monday_am_task reads the data from 'mondaycombo' I would like it to be that value. For example "$monday_am_task>variables_value", is that possible? Thanks.